# RAM extension - which one to take

Tags: memory, motherboard

My PC has a 4 GB DDR3 RAM @ 1333 MHz manufactured by Dynet. I want to extend it to 8/12GB by buying additional RAM.

My Motherboard specs show that it supports up to 16GB RAM and I have only 2 RAM slots out of which 1 is occupied with a 4GB RAM.

My question is, can I buy any DDR3 RAM clocked at 1333MHz from any manufacturer to extend my RAM or Dynet is the only option for me?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

*My existing RAM picture for reference*

[image]

Comment: I would advise going into your BIOS, F2,F10,or DEL moments after turning on the power is the most common way.  Then you can look around for memory timings things like, RAS,CAS, CL and dozens more maybe present.  If they are present you can easily make another brand work by setting each value to the larger of 2 value, except Mhz and then you need the lower of the 2. (old and new memory).  CPU-Z and other utils can tell you the timings of your existing chip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any DDR3 DIMM unbuffered non-ECC RAM (Which is most of the consumer level RAM you'll find on the market). You are not limited to just this manufacturer.

The speeds are not too vital, if you purchase sticks that are too fast they should clock down. However, as your machine is working with 1333MHz RAM, it would be advisable to stick with this and not add another variable.